# Using of loop statements and delays inside the states in fsm

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I'm trying to write vhdl code for a spartan-6 xc6slx45t for generating multiple frequencies in single channel.. That is:

- 242.72khz with 20 cycles
- 23.6khz with 1 cycle
- 243.90khz with 6 cycles
- then 23.4 khz with 386 cycles

all in single output. I just tried with one frequency here and got some issues with delays in codes..

I mentioned each states with different no.of cycles here.. But what I need is for example: when state S0 =>242.72khz with 20 cycles and then a delay in between two states, and next state S1 => 23.6khz with one cycle and then again a delay and next state and so on..)

Here i attached my code. Please help me with developing the code.. 
Thanks in advance...

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

ENTITY FSM_Example IS
    PORT (
        clk, reset, en : IN std_logic;
        output : INOUT std_logic
    );
END FSM_Example;

ARCHITECTURE Behavioral OF FSM_Example IS
    TYPE state_type IS (S0, S1, S2, S3);
    SIGNAL cur_state, next_state : state_type;
    SIGNAL count : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 5000;
    SIGNAL i : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 400;
    SIGNAL cnt : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 400;
BEGIN
    state_memory : PROCESS (clk, reset)
    BEGIN
        IF (reset = '1') THEN
            cur_state <= S0;
        ELSIF (clk = '1' AND clk'event) THEN
            IF (count = 4240 - 1) THEN
                count <= 0;
                cur_state <= next_state;
            ELSE
                count <= count + 1;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS state_memory;

    PROCESS (count)
    BEGIN
        IF (count < 1480) THEN
            output <= '1';
        ELSE
            output <= '0';
        END IF;
    END PROCESS count;

    PROCESS (en, cur_state)
    BEGIN
        CASE cur_state IS
            WHEN S0 => 
                loop0 : FOR i IN 0 TO 6 LOOP
                    EXIT loop0 WHEN i = 7;
                    cnt(i + 1) <= cnt(i) + 1;
                    IF (en = '1' AND en'event) THEN
                    ELSIF (i < 6) THEN
                        next_state <= S1;
                    ELSE
                        next_state <= S0;
                    END IF;
                END LOOP;
            WHEN S1 => 
                loop1 : FOR i IN 0 TO 1 LOOP
                    EXIT loop1 WHEN i = 2;
                    i <= i + 1;
                    IF (en = '1' AND en'event) THEN
                    ELSIF (i < 1) THEN
                        next_state <= S2;
                    ELSE
                        next_state <= S1;
                    END IF;
                END LOOP;
            WHEN S2 => 
                loop2 : FOR i IN 0 TO 20 LOOP
                    EXIT loop2 WHEN i = 21;
                    i <= i + 1;
                    IF (en = '1' AND en'event) THEN
                    ELSIF (i < 20) THEN
                        next_state <= S3;
                    ELSE
                        next_state <= S2;
                    END IF;
                END LOOP;
            WHEN S3 => 
                loop3 : FOR i IN 0 TO 386 LOOP
                    EXIT loop3 WHEN i = 387;
                    i <= i + 1;
                    IF (en = '1' AND en'event) THEN
                    ELSIF (i < 386) THEN
                        next_state <= S0;
                    ELSE
                        next_state <= S3;
                    END IF;
                END LOOP;
        END CASE;
    END PROCESS;
END Behavioral;
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write synthesize code. Then you cannot use `wait for x ns`. The FPGA does not know how to wait for x nanoseconds. It does not know what a nanosecond is.
But more of your code does not seem synthesizable. You should read-up on how to write VHDL for synthesis on FPGAs

What an FPGA does have (normally) is a clock crystal input and also . From the frequency of the clock input, you can derive how many clock cycles would be in a time period. Then you should implement a counter and insert intermediate wait-states, where the fsm waits until a specific value of the counter is reached.

E.g. If the clock input is 100 MHz, each clock pulse is 10 ns long ==> 10 clock pulses is 100 ns long. If you need smaller time step, you need to increase the clock frequency using a PLL/DCM/MMCM/etc. but you cannot do this indefinitely, as the FPGA does not support very high clock frequencies.